# Getting values from a column when another value is repeated

Tags: php, sql

I'm really newbie and I've been trying to get a result from a query without getting it. I'm sure it's quite easy for experienced users, but I'm definitely making a question after searching without finding a explained enough answer or example for me.

I have a table like this:

```
a  |  b
----------
2  | 76
----------
3  | 79
----------
3  | 84
----------
4  | 16
----------
```

I want to 'echo' in php the numbers from 'b' column if any number in 'a' column is repeated. For example, in this case, I should obtain as result: '79, 84' (because the only repeated number in 'a' column is '3')

I tried with:

```
$query=  mysql_query( "select b from table where a=3" );
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$value = $row['b'];

$j = min($row);
$k = max($row);
while ($j <= $k) {
echo $j;
echo $k;
echo $value;
$j++;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result for all data in table use this select:

```
SELECT a, GROUP_CONCAT( b ) values
FROM table
GROUP BY a
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This will group data in `table` by value of column `a`, `HAVING` will filter result only to groups with more than one member and `GRPOUP_CONCAT` will convert all values of `b` in group to single value (by default separated by comma).

[GROUP_CONCAT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)